# Converting PostgreSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I am following a tutorial on how to find recurring transactions in a bank statement dataset. I have all the data needed, but I have issues getting the queries to work with MySQL. Any idea on how to convert this to MySQL?

```
WITH transactions_with_date_diff AS (
SELECT  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY description ORDER BY accounting_date),
    accounting_date - LAG(accounting_date) OVER(PARTITION BY description ORDER BY accounting_date) AS date_diff,
    LAST_VALUE(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY description ORDER BY accounting_date) AS latest_amount,
    *
FROM transactions
)

SELECT
description,
COUNT(*) AS transactions_count,
MIN(accounting_date) AS subscription_started,
MAX(accounting_date) AS latest_transaction,
SUM(amount) AS total_amount
FROM transactions_with_date_diff
WHERE
date_diff IS NOT NULL
AND date_diff BETWEEN 25 AND 35
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

The error is:

```
Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*
    FROM transactions
    )

    SELECT
    description,
    COUNT(*) AS trans' at line 6
```

**Update**

I adjusted the SQL query based on feedback, and providing example data. Now I'm getting a different error message.

Query:

```
WITH transactions_with_date_diff AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY description ORDER BY accounting_date),
        accounting_date - LAG(accounting_date) OVER(PARTITION BY description ORDER BY accounting_date) AS date_diff,
        LAST_VALUE(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY description ORDER BY accounting_date) AS latest_amount
    FROM transactions
)

SELECT
    description,
    COUNT(*) AS transactions_count,
    MIN(accounting_date) AS subscription_started,
    MAX(accounting_date) AS latest_transaction,
    SUM(amount) AS total_amount
FROM transactions_with_date_diff
WHERE
    date_diff IS NOT NULL
    AND date_diff BETWEEN 25 AND 35
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Returning the following error:

`Query 1 ERROR: Can't group on 'transactions_count'`

Sample table data:

| id | accounting_date | description | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-31 | APPLE.COM/BILL | -24.03 |
| 2 | 2021-01-05 | ALIEXPRESS.COM ALIEXPRESS | -33 |
| 3 | 2021-01-11 | MICROSOFT*XBOX | -399.60 |

Comment: If I remember correctly * must be first in select list in mysql unless qualified with table name - but it would be better if you used column names instead of * 'Use of an unqualified * with other items in the select list may produce a parse error. To avoid this problem, use a qualified tbl_name.* reference:' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: Seems like it doesn't make a difference, however I agree that it's better to be explicit. However it seems like the error is `WITH`.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on? You need to be version 8 or above for ctes and window functions.

Comment: I'm running 8.0.22

Comment: Please add sample data and expected outcome as text to the question.

Comment: Updated SQL query and added sample data

Comment: You were originally grouping by description in the main query - did you drop this by mistake?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that way. Updated query, and it seems to work now, but only getting all entries in database with description field set to NULL.

Comment: That's a data issue query works as coded for me and produces expected results;

Comment: The query works fine: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gbFKTBnDy3fEypQckHrb6i/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should run in both MySQL and Postgres:

```
WITH transactions_with_date_diff AS (
      SELECT t.*,
            ( t.accounting_date - LAG(t.accounting_date) OVER (PARTITION BY t.description ORDER BY t.accounting_date) ) AS date_diff,
            LAST_VALUE(t.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY t.description ORDER BY t.accounting_date) AS latest_amount
      FROM transactions t
     )
SELECT tdd.description,
       COUNT(*) AS transactions_count,
       MIN(tdd.accounting_date) AS subscription_started,
       MAX(tdd.accounting_date) AS latest_transaction,
       SUM(tdd.amount) AS total_amount
FROM transactions_with_date_diff tdd
WHERE tdd.date_diff BETWEEN 25 AND 35
GROUP BY tdd.description
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY transactions_count DESC;
```

This is, in fact, Standard SQL and should run in just about any database (assuming the functionality is supported.  Note the changes:

- No unnamed columns in the CTE.  I just removed the `ROW_NUMBER()`.
- All table references have aliases
- The `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses does not use positional notation.
- The `NOT NULL` comparison is redundant.  The `BETWEEN` does not return `TRUE` for `NULL` values.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your AS backwards, you are currently trying to assign the table to the name, rather than the name to the table.

Try this:

```
WITH (
SELECT  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY description ORDER BY accounting_date),
    accounting_date - LAG(accounting_date) OVER(PARTITION BY description ORDER BY accounting_date) AS date_diff,
    LAST_VALUE(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY description ORDER BY accounting_date) AS latest_amount,
    *
FROM transactions
) AS transactions_with_date_diff
```

Comment: Thanks, however now I get the following error: `Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY description ORDER BY accounti' at line 1`

Comment: Seems like the issue is the `WITH` keyword.